# Vim: Concise comparison of registers used for delete, delete whole line, yank, and x

Tags: vim

I can find lots of partial explanations of narrow aspects of "cutting" and "copying" text in Vim and several conflicting ideas of how it works but I can't find a single concise overview. What I'm looking for is something that puts them all in one place. I'm pretty sure what I have here is wrong and has gaps but I'm wanting a COMPLETE CONCISE explanation like the following:

```
key   operation     register used   notes
y     yank          "" "0 and "1
x     del 1 char    "1              why doesn't xxxxxx fill all registers?
dd    del line      "" and "1
d[?]  del [motion]  "1

a p (put) with no specified register will put from register "1 (I think)

if an operation uses register "1 to store deleted/yanked text, then "1's
previous contents will be pushed to "2 and so on up to register "9 whose
previous content will disappear.

a "[alphanumeric] (quote followed by alphanumeric) before a d or y will
put the result into that register in addition to the registers it would
normally go in.
```

Yes, this question is partially duplicated many times over by people asking details on one particular operation. If there are any operations I've missed that put text into the delete or yank registers, I'd like to know those too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find the complete explanation at `:help "0`. Your summary is mostly correct, however, you're missing on the *small deletes*, which go into a special `"-` register.

```
key   operation     register used     notes
y     yank          "" and "0
x     del 1 char    "" and "-         small delete register
dd    del line      "" and "1
d[?]  del [motion]  "" and ("1 or "-) depending on the length of the text

a p (put) with no specified register will put from the default register ""
```

Comment: Yep.. `:help "0` is awesome and has everything in less than a page worth. I didn't know how to find it in the help. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

For those too lazy to type `:help "0` as indicated by Ingo's answer, here's my abbreviated version of what the help says:

> 1. Unnamed register ""
>
> Vim fills this register with text deleted with the "d", "c", "s", "x" commands or copied with the yank "y" command, regardless of whether or not a specific register was used (e.g.  "xdd).  This is like the unnamed register is pointing to the last used register.  Thus when appending using an uppercase register name, the unnamed register contains the same text as the named register. Vim uses the contents of the unnamed register for any put command (p or P) which does not specify a register.  Additionally you can access it with the name '"'.  This means you have to type two double quotes.  Writing to the "" register writes to register "0.
>
> 2. Numbered registers "0 to "9
>
> Vim fills these registers with text from yank and delete commands. Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command,unless the command specified another register with ["x]. Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or change command, unless the command specified another register or the text is less than one line (the small delete register is used then).  An exception is made for the delete operator with these movement commands: %, (, ), `, /, ?, n, N, { and }.  Register "1 is always used then.  The "- register is used as well if the delete is within a line.
>
> With each successive deletion or change, Vim shifts the previous contents
>   of register 1 into register 2, 2 into 3, and so forth, losing the previous
>   contents of register 9.
>
> 3. Small delete register "-
>
> This register contains text from commands that delete less than one line,
>   except when the command specifies a register with ["x].